# Nginx with php in one subdirectory

Tags: php, nginx

I have a website in pure HTML. Now I have to add a sub-directory (demo) containing PHP files. I set up two locations in my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     mydomain.com;

    access_log      /mydomain.com/access.log;

    location / {
        root        /www;
        index       index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /demo {
        root        /www/demo;
        index       /demo/index.php;
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    location ~ /demo/.*\.php$ {
        root        /www/demo;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /www/demo$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny         all;
    }
}
```

Now the mydomain.com works just fine, but when I try to access mydomain.com/demo/, it keeps complaining

```
No input file specified.
```

What's the problem with this script? I guess some path is not correctly setup like fastcgi_index: should it be /demo/index.php? I've tried different combinations but none works. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your `fastcgi_param` should be `/www$fastcgi_script_name` because the variable is the full URI request. [Source](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#.24fastcgi_script_name).