# Serving PHP from a subdirectory using nginx + php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, subdirectory, mirror

The main static website (mirror) is located in: `/home/mirrors/mirror`

I'm trying setup PHP website only in the subdirectory `/home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/`. So far it loads PHP, but all the images, css and url links point to `/home/mirrors/mirror/filename*` instead of `/home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/filename*`

I've tried with:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

But that results in error logs showing:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/phpweb/index.php

The closest to working config is the incorrect way of setting the path with:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mirrors/mirror$fastcgi_script_name;
```

What am I overlooking? Here's the entire config. Basically it works except that images/css/js are not pointed to the phpweb/ directory. My config seems to be missing some lines that will allow statics inside of         root /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb; to point to that folder.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    server_name  mirrors.domain.com;
   if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        root /home/mirrors/mirror;
        index index.html index.htm;
        include /home/mirrors/Nginx-Fancyindex-Theme/fancyindex.conf;
        }

    location /phpweb {
        root /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb;
        index /phpweb/index.php;
        }


    location ~ /phpweb/.*\.php$ {
        root /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb;
#        try_files $uri =404;
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mirrors/mirror$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

[Here's where I found a config example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990295/nginx-with-php-in-one-subdirectory)

**UPDATE:** Here's updated config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    server_name  mirrors.domain.com;
    root /home/mirrors/mirror;
   if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm;
        include /home/mirrors/Nginx-Fancyindex-Theme/fancyindex.conf;
        }

    location /phpweb {
        index /phpweb/index.php;
        }


    location ~ /phpweb/.*\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Which results in:

> Warning: include(/home/mirrors/mirror/include/site.inc): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 78
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/mirrors/mirror/include/site.inc' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 78
>
> Warning: include(/home/mirrors/mirror/include/langchooser.inc): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 81
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/mirrors/mirror/include/langchooser.inc' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 81
>
> Warning: include(/home/mirrors/mirror/include/ip-to-country.inc):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 84
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/mirrors/mirror/include/ip-to-country.inc' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 84
>
> Warning: include(/home/mirrors/mirror/include/layout.inc): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 87
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/mirrors/mirror/include/layout.inc' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 87
>
> Warning: include(/home/mirrors/mirror/include/last_updated.inc):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 92
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/mirrors/mirror/include/last_updated.inc' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc on line 92
>
> Warning: include_once(/home/mirrors/mirror/include/releases.inc):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/branches.inc on line 2
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/mirrors/mirror/include/releases.inc' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/branches.inc on line 2
>
> Warning: include_once(/home/mirrors/mirror/include/version.inc):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/branches.inc on line 3
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/mirrors/mirror/include/version.inc' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/branches.inc on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mirror_setcookie() in
>   /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/index.php on line 44

Previously (original config pasted in this post) there we no php errors and the page loads. But images/statics were broken as described above.

Answer (score 1):

The `root` directive specifies the part of the physical path which is prefixed to the URI to find the physical file. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

So in the configuration you posted, it seems to me that the value for `root` should be the same in all three locations:

```
root /home/mirrors/mirror;
```

In fact, it is common to specify the `root` directive once in the `server` block and allow it to be inherited into each location. For example:

```
root /home/mirrors/mirror;
location / { ... }
location /phpweb { ... }
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had at first but it results in:
Warning: include(/home/mirrors/mirror/include/site.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mirrors/mirror/phpweb/include/prepend.inc

About 20 of those lines. Which would mean I would have to manually set path in the code provided by PHP (http://php.net/mirroring.php). Hopefully there is a way to configure Nginx so that the /phpweb/ isn't omitted? Just reverted to your config suggestion, but only the PHP errors show, where as with the original config above the page loads but all statics and links omit /phpweb/. :/